# Android - How to remove unwanted gaps when using LinearLayout with weights

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a vertical LinearLayout that contains 2 horizontal LinearLayouts. Below the vertical LL, I have another horizontal LL. Since I'm using the weight attribute, I've made either the height or width attributes of the layouts = 0dp.

Code -

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
                android:text="back" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:id="@+id/buttonRefresh"
                android:text="refresh" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:id="@+id/buttonScore1"
                android:text="Score: " />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:id="@+id/buttonScore2"
                android:text="Score: " />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlayer1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:text="P1"
        />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlayer2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:text="P2" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is how it looks -

[image: Unwanted gaps]

**As you can see, there are unwanted gaps (and rounded corners) between the elements. How do I remove the white spaces?**

Comment: set background color as your button color to that individual Linear layout.

Comment: show full xml please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace All your buttons with material buttons

`app:cornerRadius="0dp"` this will remove corners

And `android:background="#000000"` this is for expand the buttons to full height

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:cornerRadius="0dp" //
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.25"
android:background="#000000"
android:id="@+id/buttonRefresh"
android:text="refresh" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code I just added a background to your Linear Layout

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@color/purple_500"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
            android:text="back" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:id="@+id/buttonRefresh"
            android:text="refresh" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/purple_500"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:id="@+id/buttonScore1"
            android:text="Score: " />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:id="@+id/buttonScore2"
            android:text="Score: " />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/purple_500"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlayer1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="P1"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlayer2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="P2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1.0">

        <Button
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="BACK"
            android:padding="1px"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:id="@+id/buttonBack"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="SCORE:"
            android:padding="1px"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:id="@+id/buttonScore1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="P1"
            android:padding="1px"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlayer1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1.0">

        <Button
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="REFRESH"
            android:padding="1px"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:id="@+id/buttonRefresh"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="SCORE:"
            android:padding="1px"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:id="@+id/buttonScore2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="P2"
            android:padding="1px"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlayer2"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've put a padding of 1px for each `Button` because of Android bugs on rendering text in a `Button`.